# Odoo 14 : psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: role "admin" does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, odoo-14

my installation of odoo 14 isn't working. its debags like :

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "admin" does not exist
```

whats my config file:

```
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = paroli321
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = admin
```

Comment: I think your postgresql is not installed properly. I think if you are using linux system, you should use this script.https://github.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript

Comment: Try to create the `admin` role. You can check odoo documentation on how to configure PostgreSQL on [windows](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/install.html#postgresql), [Linux](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/install.html#id13) or [MacOS](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/administration/install/install.html#id22)

Answer (score 0):

The error said that there is no postgresql user named "admin". So create one with the following command:

```
$createuser admin -W --interactive
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) <-- no
Shall the new role be allowed to create databases? (y/n) <-- yes
Shall the new role be allowed to create more new roles? (y/n) <-- no
Password: <-- type password here, in your case is "paroli321"
```